# C# calculation returns 0

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and this code always returns 0.00 and I don't know what is the reason. Could anyone help?
It is a console program and a possible input is

```
sofia
1500
```

the result should be 120.00

```
using System;

namespace TradeComissions
{
    class TradeComissions
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var town = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            var amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double result = 0.0;

            if(town == "sofia")
            {
                if (amount >= 0 && amount <= 500) 
                {                 
                    result = amount * (5 / 100);    
                }
                else if (amount >= 500 && amount <= 1000) 
                {         
                    result = amount * (7 / 100);    
                }
                else if (amount >= 1000 && amount <= 10000) 
                {       
                    result = amount * (8 / 100);    
                }
                else if (amount > 10000) 
                {                          
                    result = amount * (12 / 100);   
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `(5 / 100)` is zero. `(5.0 / 100)` is `0.05`.

Comment: Yup, all your divisions are being done with integer arithmetic...

Comment: `8 / 100 = 0` as they are marked as integers, use `8.0 / 100` or `8 / 100.0` to make sure it's a double calculation

Comment: By the way, if you just removed parentheses, the result would be correct.

Comment: Thank you all. adding .0 helped. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a mathematical division between 2 integers where denom is bigger that numerator e.g. `5 / 100`, that operation result into an integer too (zero), do instead:

```
result = amount * (5.0 / 100);
```

Comment: why was the duplicate marking not stopping you from answering?

Comment: hummm kind of weird, it was closed 3 minutes ago, my answer came 1 minute after closing....

Comment: Yeah, hence my question :) Seems it's a known [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible) :)

Comment: Well, it is more concerning that rep-farming is still successful on this site, even for extremly obvious dupes -.-

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var town = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    var amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double result = 0.0;

    if (town == "sofia")
    {
        if (amount >= 0 && amount <= 500)
        {
            result = amount * (0.05);
        }
        else if (amount >= 500 && amount <= 1000)
        {
            result = amount * (0.07);
        }
        else if (amount >= 1000 && amount <= 10000)
        {
            result = amount * (0.08);
        }
        else if (amount > 10000)
        {
            result = amount * (0.12);
        }
    }
    double f = result;

    Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```